# ERROR:HDLParsers:800 - Type of RAM1 is incompatible with type of RAM2

Tags: vhdl

I'm getting following error in my VHDL code,

```
architecture Behavioral of Con_Int is
    type camera_log1 is array (0 to 2047) of std_logic;
    signal RAM1 : camera_log1 := (others => '0');
    type camera_log2 is array (0 to 2047) of std_logic;
    signal RAM2 : camera_log2 := (others => '0');
    signal sync_bit1 :std_logic:='0';
begin
    process(sync_bit1,rdatalatch)
        variable cnt1 :integer range 0 to 2048:=0;    
    begin
        if sync_bit1 = '1' then
            if rising_edge(rdatalatch)then
                if cnt1<2047 then
                    cnt1 := cnt1 +1;
                    RAM2(1 to 2047) <= RAM2(0 to 2046);
                    RAM2(0) <= blk_out;                                  
                elsif cnt1 = 2047 then
                    RAM1 <= RAM2;   
                end if;
            end if;
        else
            cnt1:=0; 
        end if;
    end process;
end behavioral;
```

but I have an error as below;

> ERROR:HDLParsers:800 -"xxx" Type of RAM1 is incompatible with type of RAM2.

But both are same data type!, thats why I confused!.

Answer (score 3):

The type of `RAM1` is `camera_log1`, and the type of `RAM2` is `camera_log2`, so they are **not** the same type... the two types just happens to be declared to `array (0 to 2047) of std_logic`.

One solution is to use `std_logic_vector` instead of making your own array of `std_logic`, and then declare `RAM1` and `RAM2` as:

```
signal RAM1 : std_logic_vector(0 to 2047) := (others => '0');
signal RAM2 : std_logic_vector(0 to 2047) := (others => '0');
```

Other solution is to make just one `camera_log` and then use for both `RAM1` and `RAM2`.

```
type camera_log is array (0 to 2047) of std_logic;
```

Comment: Since they have the same definition (array of std_logic), you can cast between them (RAM1 <= camera_log1(RAM2)). The cast is required since VHDL is strongly typed.

Comment: IEEE std 1076-2008,  6.2 Type declarations, "The types created by the elaboration of distinct type definitions are distinct types."  9.3.6 Type conversions, "Explicit type conversions are allowed between closely related types. In particular, a type is closely related to itself." Two array types are closely related if they have "the same dimensionality and the element types are closely related". (The term 'cast' only appears once in the standard (21.2.2 Registering callbacks) and it's use refers to non-VHDL code, the VHDL term is 'type conversion').